# How much of DQB2 is dialogue/quests?

Tags: dragon-quest-builders-2

I played the demo of Dragon Quest Builders 2 on Switch, and I didn't like 2 things about it:

1. The amount of dialogue that I felt I had to skip through because I wasn't interested in it
2. The boring quests that seemed like they weren't optional and that seemed to go on and on forever

I want to buy the full game and play the game in sandbox mode, but if it's all dialogue/quests I won't enjoy it.

So how much of the game is like that? Is it only at the start as like a tutorial to teach you how to play? Or is the whole game like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a sandbox island BUT you gotta sit through the whole story and quest part to get to it (you can access it early but don't have all the materials available).

Overall, I would say around 20-30 hours of story/quest before finishing the game.